# VBA. How to exclude hide sheet from this export code?

Tags: vba, show-hide

```
Sub SaveShtsAsBook() 
    ‘Select all visible and hide sheet’
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, SheetName$, MyFilePath$, N& 
    MyFilePath$ = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _ 
    Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4) 
    With Application 
        .ScreenUpdating = False 
        .DisplayAlerts = False 
         '      End With
        On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists
        MkDir MyFilePath '<< create a folder
        For N = 1 To Sheets.Count 
            Sheets(N).Activate 
            SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name 
            Cells.Copy 
            Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet) 
            With ActiveWorkbook 
                With .ActiveSheet 
                    .Paste 
                    .Name = SheetName 
                    [A1].Select 
                End With 
                 'save book in this folder
                .SaveAs Filename:=MyFilePath _ 
                & "\" & SheetName & ".xlsx" 
                .Close SaveChanges:=True 
            End With 
            .CutCopyMode = False 
        Next 
    End With 
    Sheet1.Activate 
End Sub
```

I want to create individual excel workbook with only 1 sheet inside but I do not want to include those sheet that are hiding, yet I cant delete them cause I need them next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to copy visible sheets, then why not only copy visible sheets?

Can't you do something like:

```
For N = 1 To Sheets.Count 
    If Sheets(N).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
         ... Copy the sheet
    End It
Next N
```

Or do you mean you want to copy the hidden sheets, but have them remain hidden in the target workbook?  In which case you can set the Visible property after you've created the new sheet.

Or you might look at using `Worksheet.Copy` to copy worksheets rather than copying and pasting the worksheet content.  This will be more efficient as it will avoid the need to use the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. 
I have a workbook, that contains many sheets which have visible and hide ones. I only want to export each visible sheet to individual workbook. 
this current code above can do the export for all the sheet in the workbook but I have to delete them 1 by 1 after that. Hope that explains my situation.

Comment: @cheesengng - when you say "doesn't work", what happens?  Your code has other potential problems that you could probably solve by using `Worksheet.Copy` instead of cut/paste.  Using cut/paste requires you to have the correct sheet active at all times, and I'm not sure that's the case in your code: after your call to `Workbooks.Add`, you appear to immediately use `ActiveSheet` for the Paste, which may not be the sheet you think it is.

Comment: The code itself is working fine, but this code also export those sheets that are hidden. I have no idea how to modify your code to my current one. Please help